# Images are displayed bigger than the actual size

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a wordpress theme for photographers but I notice all my images are been displayed bigger than the actual size I upload. They are stretching to the screen resolution I guess, but the problem is that if users have such a big resolution the images seem to be very poor quality, I would like to change this to show pictures at their original size, or only stretch until their max original size. But I can't quite find the code responsible for this changes,

This is the gallery link 
http://prophotosjapan.com/gallery/harbour-wedding/

But even when you open them individually like this
http://prophotosjapan.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Engagement31-2-684x1024.jpg

Engagement31-2-684x1024.jpg (JPEG Image, 684 × 1024 pixels) - Scaled (78%)

Is this the code that I should change?

Comment: Masonry CSS is not configured properly. Masonry items are set to take 24.9% of the grid (not ideal) You need to add media queries to sort the matter out properly and insert more items as viewer width increases. https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Nn71.jpg and also some images have fixed dimensions  https://i.stack.imgur.com/67gyA.jpg

Comment: Thank for replying. So please disconsider the other galleries I changed the type of gallery for masonry, I want to use the Folio type/class the problem is when you click on pictures, they are displayed too big, and not at the original size

Comment: If you mean you want to display the photos at their actual size in centimeters, you're out of luck. HTML doesn't look at the physical size, only at the number of pixels. With the example photo, the size is 684x1024 pixels, and it has a DPI of 120 which HTML ignores. So HTML can only display it at 684x1024 pixels or at a size you specify explicitly. If you want the picture to come out at its natural size on the screen (I assume to be 96dpi) you will have to calculate the pixel sizes manually - in this particular case 96/120 times 684x1024 = 547x819 pixels.

Comment: Oh, WRT your last comment: if you display the image in the browser and you have the "fit to window" option on, then the browser will scale the picture down to the window if it's to big and say "scaled". But that has nothing to do with how you display it in a HTML page.

Comment: Ok guys thank you very much for the replies, I guess I'm not explaining the problem correctly. I uploaded the picture with 684x1024, the thing is the pictures inside the browser is fitting the window, so if you use a big resolution lets say 4k for example, the image will be displayed to fill the screen and will be scaled, loosing quality. If I open the same picture I uploaded to wordpress, using a standard image viewer it will be displayed at it's full size, not scaled. I want to reproduce that on the browser but all my images seems to display scaled

Comment: @massaki Ah, I see. My monitor isn't big enough to cause that, so I didn't notice. But apparently, there is some JavaScript on the page that changes the sizes of the images dynamically to fit the container. Find it, and remove the offending parts. The CSS in the stylesheet is OK.